# Create a oneToMany String field in JBoss Forge

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-forge

I currently use the 1.4.3 Final version of JBoss Forge, and I am trying to add a field to an Entity. In fact I have a Task Entity, and I would like to add a field which is a list of tags, thanks to a Set.

I tried to do :

`field oneToMany --named tags --fieldType string`

`field oneToMany --named tags --fieldType java.lang.String`

`field oneToMany --named tags --fieldType java.lang.String.java`

But it seems that the field type must be an Entity as well. Should I create another Entity called Tag, with a String field?

Answer (score 0):

In JPA, you can't have `@OneToMany` relationship with String, use `@ElementCollection`. However I can help you with JBoss Forge You will probably have to add this field manually.